# Why Both 8GB USB Flash Drives Have Different Integrities?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, fat32

**USB 3.0 SuperTalent Express DUO 8GB** recently had its partition corrupted and declared itself "write-protected" and I was told in chat by @sidran32 that this usually means that flash drive gone bad due to writing cycles limit being reached. Having this thumbdrive for over a year being used infrequently, I was in doubt and referred to SuperTalent's support. I was given recovery tool which I executed but it failed first time prompting me to reinsert it. After that, I formatted it with Windows 7 integrated format utility since recovery tool offered to do this as well which was successful.

The problem as I have noticed is with integrity of SuperTalent:

[image]

Compare above to **SanDisk's Micro Cruzer 8GB**:

[image]

Am I missing something? Both thumbdrives are of 8GB and have same **FAT32** file system.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of a flash memory cell is reduced each time the cell is used. After some time, a much-used cell becomes faulty and cannot be used anymore. Then it will be automatically sorted out by the flash memory controller and marked as *not available*.

The most logical explanation to me is the one you already got: Your Super Talent flash drive seems to have several "sorted-out" cells.

However, since you said that you didn't use your drive very often, another explanation could be that Super Talent typically sell their flash drives with a lower capacity compared to the ones from SanDisk. Nevertheless, the minimum capacity a factory-new 8 GB flash drive should provide is 8,000,000,000 bytes (which is not the case with this Super Talent drive).

Please note that 1 *GB* (10<sup>9</sup> bytes) [is not equal to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Specific_units_of_IEC_60027-2_A.2_and_ISO.2FIEC_80000) 1 *GiB* (1024<sup>3</sup> bytes). Drive manufacturers use the exact SI prefixes which often leads to confusion dependent on which units are used by the operating systems to display the drive capacity.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand. 1 byte is 8 bits. Since when 1 byte turned to be 4 bits?

Comment: SuperTalent support offer me RMA. Should I proceed or live with that and see how it will perform? SuperTalent give limited lifetime warranty which I don't know precisely what it means.